# Error during file write in simple PHP caching

Tags: php, caching

I made a simple database driven php website. Now i am trying to implement some simple caching to the site. i tried this from somewhere

```
<?php
      $reqfilename="test";
      $cachetime = 60*5; // 5 minutes
      $cachefile = "cache/".$reqfilename.".html";
      $cf2="cache/".$reqfilename."2.html";
      if (file_exists($cachefile) && ((time() - $cachetime) < filemtime($cachefile))) 
      { 
         include($cachefile);
         exit;
      }
      ob_start(); 
?>
CONTENT OF THE PAGE GOES HERE
<?php   
        $fp = @fopen($cf2, 'w'); 
        if($fp){
            fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
            fclose($fp); 
            rename($cf2,$cachefile);
        }   
        ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

But what if the cache file is being renamed and someone requests the page. Will there be an error displayed or just the user will experience a delay?

To reduce the time of the cache file being modified only, I am using rename instead of directly writing on the original cache file

**Correct code to do this** (based on answer by webbiedave below)

```
<?php
      $reqfilename="test";
      $cachetime = 60*5; // 5 minutes
      $cachefile = "cache/".$reqfilename.".html";

      if (file_exists($cachefile) && ((time() - $cachetime) < filemtime($cachefile))) 
      { 
         include($cachefile);
         exit;
      }
      ob_start(); 
?>
CONTENT OF THE PAGE GOES HERE
<?php   
        $fp = @fopen($cachefile, 'w'); 
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp); 
    }

    ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the file isn't the source of your problem. The main race condition with your script is multiple requests detecting an expired mtime and all writing to `test2.html`.

A better approach is to perform an exclusive, non-blocking [flock](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) (assuming non-windows) immediately after detecting an expired mtime, buffer the output, overwrite the file and release the lock. If `flock` returns false, then another process is writing to it and the current process should skip the write entirely.

If a request is made during the lock, the web server will wait until the file write is complete (and the lock released), then serve the file.

Comment: Thanks.. thats exactly what I was looking for.. earlier didn't thought of LOCK_NB. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your source will work properly because you don't delete the cache-file

Comment: Why should i delete the cache file. The file is being renamed as the file which will be used to display the page.